# Enclose title within a div?

Tags: title, post-class

I'm using this code to display a page within my front page. I would like to learn how to add a div / spacer to isolate the page title... If I try to add a div class within the php code then it throws errors.

**Question: How can I add a div to the title within this bit of code?**

```
<div class="frontpage">
<?php 
$page_id = 2945; 
$page_data = get_page( $page_id ); 
echo '<h3>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h3>'; //enclose the title within a div/spacer???
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change heading from

```
echo '<h3>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h3>';
```

like

```
echo '<div class="class-name">'. $page_data->post_title .'</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian - you must have posted that just as I was adding my answer - Thankyou  :-)